# How to force Hibernate 3.3 or 3.5 to use CGLib instead of Javassist?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, cglib

Is it still possible to force Hibernate 3.3 or 3.5 to use CGLib instead of Javassist?  In my properties file, I set

```
hibernate.bytecode.provider = cglib
```

But this doesn't seem to do it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: this begs the question.... why? this is internal hibernate stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems some people didn't read my answer correctly so I'll rephrase: your `hibernate.properties` looks correct, the property is well defined, it should work. So, sorry for the question but is CGlib on the classpath?

**Update:** Just tested and it works for me. Here is the output I get at initialization time:

```
15 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.0.SP1
18 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.bytecode.provider=cglib}
20 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : cglib
```

PS: Note that [CGLIB support has been deprecated](http://relation.to/16658.lace) recently (this doesn't mean you won't be able to use CGLIB but the integration it not maintained anymore).

Comment: I don't know how it works in your environment (maybe you are running Hibernate packaged with JBoss?), but Hibernate needs a system property or a `hibernate.properties` in classpath on class creation (stupid!) to capture the bytecode provider setting. So having `cglib` in classpath is not a root of the issue. Both 3.3.1 and 3.3.2 do not work "out of he box".

Comment: @dma_k Read the question again, the OP **does** have a `hibernate.properties` file (*"In my properties file, I set"*) on the classpath, so this part is implied by my answer (*"and your property is well defined"*). Maybe **you** misunderstood what the OP and I said, in which case, I ask you to reconsider your vote. I never said the property file was not needed.

Comment: @dma_k The log trace even illustrates that I have a `hibernate.properties`. You totally misread what I said.

Comment: Oh, yea, I missed that. Sorry for fuzz. +1

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, also put

```
hibernate.properties
```

into some source folder and remember to have the hibermate-cglib-repack in dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-cglib-repack</artifactId>
    <version>2.1_3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Starting from Hibernate 3.3.2 the repackaged version of cglib is not needed. And, at least for 3.2.x, on need to speiofy either `-Dhibernate.bytecode.provider=cglib` system property or to create a classpath-wide `hibernate.properties` with the same property defined.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that CGLIB library is not developed for about 4 years. You should do everything however to make your code working with Javassist, which is still actively maintained.