# how to force hibernate to use javassist?

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, glassfish

I'm using jpa+hibernate on glassfish 3.1.1 .
I found that cglib is buggy and don't work with jersey so I'm obliged to change to javassist .
how can i do that ?
I tried to configure that in my persistence.xml file but it failed.

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="oci_server-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.provider" value="javassist"/>

        <jta-data-source>oci_test</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with setting byte code provider in hibernate application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977765/problem-with-setting-byte-code-provider-in-hibernate-application)